# why am I getting an "invalid_request"?

Tags: fusionauth

I am trying to use FusionAuth's passwordless login feature. I am getting an error "Invalid redirect uri", when I try clicking on the link in the received email. I am using the php client.

```
    $request = array();
    $request["applicationId"] = $_SESSION['applicationID'];
    $request["loginId"] = $email;
    $target="http://8615582f3e2c.ngrok.io/index.php/Configure/MyFormEmployees";
    $request["state"]["redirect_uri"] = $target;
    $request["state"]["client_id"]=$_SESSION['applicationID'];
    $request["state"]["response_type"]= "code";
    $request["state"]["scope"]= "openid";
    $request["state"]["state"]= "CSRF123";
    $requestJ = json_encode($request);   //convert the array into json

    $result = $_SESSION['client']->startPasswordlesslogin($requestJ);
```

And this is what I am getting in the email as a link:
http://localhost:9011/oauth2/passwordless/5NHh37raOrUpSO4TlJcL-pY39i1TdasNd9vTTqqaiLk?tenantId=34303566-6466-3234-6565-656233663263&client_id=32688330-1630-4e0d-a4de-8ae45c3ca527&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FXX15582f3e2c.ngrok.io%2Findex.php%2FConfigure%2FMyFormEmployees&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=CSRF123

and this causes the invalid URI error. How can I get this link to work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `http://XX15582f3e2c.ngrok.io/index.php/Configure/MyFormEmployees` to the list of Authorized redirect URIs. In the FusionAuth console, see `Applications > Edit > OAuth > Authorized redirect URLs`.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I actually already have that. When I pull the redirect uri out of the email link and paste it into my browser, it seems to find the page fine. I saw a comment of yours to someone else with the same issue that they needed to set "use exact uri in redirect" to false in the server. Which server are you referring to? My apache? Somewhere in php.ini? Any other ideas?